# Config file to define JSON Schema Structure in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a PySpark application that reads the JSON file in a dataframe through a defined Schema. code sample below

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("domain", StringType(), True),
     StructField("timestamp", LongType(), True),                            
])
df= sqlContext.read.json(file, schema)
```

I need a way to find how can I define this schema in a kind of config or ini file etc. And read that in the main the PySpark application.

This will help me to modify schema for the changing JSON if there is any need in future without changing the main PySpark code.

Answer (score 12):

`StructType` provides `json` and `jsonValue` methods which can be used to obtain `json` and `dict` representation respectively and `fromJson` which can be used to convert Python dictionary to `StructType`.

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("domain", StringType(), True),
    StructField("timestamp", LongType(), True),                            
])

StructType.fromJson(schema.jsonValue())
```

The only thing you need beyond that is built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) module to parse input to the `dict` that can be consumed by `StructType`.

For Scala version see [How to create a schema from CSV file and persist/save that schema to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42004245)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a JSON file named schema.json in the below format

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "first_fields",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "double_field",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "double"
    }
  ],
  "type": "struct"
}
```

Create a struct schema from reading this file

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("s3://<bucket>/schema.json")
text = rdd.collect()[0][1]
dict = json.loads(str(text))
custom_schema = StructType.fromJson(dict)
```

After that, you can use struct as a schema to read the JSON file

```
val df=spark.read.json("path", custom_schema)
```

Comment: Hi i Try this in Databricks pyspark not working rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("s3://<bucket>/schema.json")
text = rdd.collect()[0][1]
dict = json.loads(str(text))
custom_schema = StructType.fromJson(dict)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort

Comment: @user3843858 Any exception or error trace to look at?. Also please specify the version which u are using

Comment: its working issue was int i have change  integer, working fine . thanks a lot