# Generate Spark schema code/persist and reuse schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am implementing some Spark Structured Streaming transformations from a Parquet data source. In order to read the data into a streaming DataFrame, one has to specify the schema (it cannot be automatically inferred). The schema is really complex and manually writing the schema code will be a very complex task.

Can you suggest a walkaround? Currently I am creating a batch DataFrame beforehand (using the same data source), Spark infers the schema and then I save the schema to a Scala object and use it as an input for the Structured Streaming reader.

I don't think it is a reliable or a well performing solution. Please suggest how to generate the schema code automatically or somehow persist the schema in a file and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> By default, Structured Streaming from file based sources requires you
> to specify the schema, rather than rely on Spark to infer it
> automatically. This restriction ensures a consistent schema will be
> used for the streaming query, even in the case of failures. For ad-hoc
> use cases, you can reenable schema inference by setting
> `spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference` to `true`.

You could also open a shell, read one of the parquet files with automatic schema inference enabled, and [save the schema to JSON for later reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42004558/14620730). You only have to do this one time, so it might be faster / more efficient than doing the similar-sounding workaround you're using now.

Comment: Hey, I think saving the schema to JSON and reusing it is a great idea but the example that you linked doesn't work for me. I get the following error, when trying to use the schema: overloaded method value schema with alternatives:
  (schemaString: String)org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader <and>
  (schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader
 cannot be applied to (Option[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType])

Comment: What about popping open a spark-shell and just loading one of your parquet files as a plain, old, non-streaming DataFrame just using SparkSession.read.parquet(), and using its schema?