# Spark fails to load data frame from elasticsearch due to field format exception

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

My dataframe fails due to NumberFormatException on one of the nested JSON fields when reading from Elasticsearch .
I am not providing any schema as it should be inferred automatically from Elastic.

```scala
package org.arc
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._
import scala.io.Source
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction
import scala.io.Codec
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.util.Utils
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ concat, lit }
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructType, StructField, StringType };
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer

object SparkOnES {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkESTest")
      .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C://SparkScala//SparkLocal//spark-warehouse")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    //1.Read Sample JSON
    import spark.implicits._

    //val myjson = spark.read.json("C:\\Users\\jasjyotsinghj599\\Desktop\\SampleTest.json")
    // myjson.show(false)

    //2.Read Data from ES
    val esdf = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .option("es.nodes", "XXXXXX")
      .option("es.port", "80")
      .option("es.query", "?q=*")
      .option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
      .option("pushdown", "true")
      .option("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .load("batch_index/ticket")

    esdf.createOrReplaceTempView("esdf")
    spark.sql("Select * from esdf limit 1").show(false)
    val esdf_fltr_lt = esdf.take(1)

  }
}
```

The ErrorStack says that it cannot parse the input field.Looking at the exception, this issue seems to have caused due to mismatch in the type of data expected ( int, float, double ) and received ( string ) :

```scala
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "161.60"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:277)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:29)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.parseLong(ScalaValueReader.scala:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader$$anonfun$longValue$1.apply(ScalaValueReader.scala:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader$$anonfun$longValue$1.apply(ScalaValueReader.scala:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.checkNull(ScalaValueReader.scala:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.longValue(ScalaValueReader.scala:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.readValue(ScalaValueReader.scala:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ScalaRowValueReader.readValue(ScalaEsRowValueReader.scala:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.parseValue(ScrollReader.java:770)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:720)
    ... 25 more
18/04/25 23:33:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, localhost): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopParsingException: Cannot parse value [161.60] for field [tvl_tkt_tot_chrg_amt]
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:723)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.map(ScrollReader.java:867)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:710)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.readHitAsMap(ScrollReader.java:476)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.readHit(ScrollReader.java:401)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRepository.java:393)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.hasNext(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:784)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "161.60"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:277)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:29)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.parseLong(ScalaValueReader.scala:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader$$anonfun$longValue$1.apply(ScalaValueReader.scala:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader$$anonfun$longValue$1.apply(ScalaValueReader.scala:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.checkNull(ScalaValueReader.scala:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.longValue(ScalaValueReader.scala:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.serialization.ScalaValueReader.readValue(ScalaValueReader.scala:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ScalaRowValueReader.readValue(ScalaEsRowValueReader.scala:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.parseValue(ScrollReader.java:770)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:720)
    ... 25 more

18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.1.2.244:4040
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/04/25 23:33:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
```

Comment: "I am not providing any schema as it should be inferred automatically from" - you should provide one. Inference is not reliable (as the example shows) and is expensive.

Comment: I am not aware for how to provide schema for data coming in from ElasticSearch into Dataframe. Can you direct me to an appropriate link

Comment: Define schema as usually, and pass as to `schema` method of `DataFrameReader`? `spark.read.schema(...). ... load(...)`

Comment: Ok i will give a try But its a nested json and has total of 150 fields with 4 nested fields which are further nested

Comment: Easy way to start is to use inferred one, and fix gradually. You can use JSON as an intermediate representation for easy editing (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38276588/9613318) in Python, but there are the same methods in Scala).